# How does the emerson effect produce a higher rate of photosynthesis?

Tags: photosynthesis

Can anyone explain how the emerson effect works to increase the rate of photosynthesis, and as the original studies were done over 50 years ago, how much research is still done into this area? Or is it well understood now as to not need further work?

I am obviously not a biologist but from what I have been reading, photosystem 2 absorbs light at 680nm due to the primary electron donor p680 and photosystem 1 at 700nm due to p700. The rate of photosynthesis when exposed to light at these 2 wavelengths simultaneously is greater than the sum of the rate of photosynthesis if exposed to these wavelengths separately. Sorry for any mistakes, I am just starting to try to learn about it. I'm interested to find out how this higher rate of photosynthesis occurs when using light in the red and far red end of the spectrum at the same time.

Comment: You are expected to show some attempt to answer this on your own, even a brief description of what you know about the emerson effect would be beneficial. You may also want to look up photosystem 1 and photosystem 2.

Comment: I have added some more info into the question to show what I think I know so far.